# Strange linking error with intel mkl using gcc under ubuntu

Tags: gcc, intel-mkl

I want to use intel mkl in some optimazation problems, so I use intel example to test it.
test.cpp:

```
    #include <mkl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef struct {
        double re;
        double im;
    } complex16;

    extern "C" void cblas_zdotc_sub(int, const void*, int, const void*, int, void*);

    #define N 5

    int main()
    {
        int n, inca = 1, incb = 1, i;
        complex16 a[N], b[N], c;
        n = N;

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i].re = (double)i;
            a[i].im = (double)i * 2.0;
            b[i].re = (double)(n - i);
            b[i].im = (double)i * 2.0;
        }

        cblas_zdotc_sub(n, (void*)a, inca, (void*)b, incb, (void *)&c);
        printf("The complex dot product is: ( %6.2f, %6.2f) ", c.re, c.im);
        return 0;
    }
```

when I compile it with "g++ -I/home/l/intel/mkl/include -w test.cpp -        L"/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64" "/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64"/libmkl_intel_lp64.a -Wl,--start-group "/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64"/libmkl_intel_thread.a "/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64"/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -L"/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/../compiler/lib/intel64" -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -L/home/l/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -o template", every thing is fine...

But if I separate the compile step and the link step, it gave me a link error:

test.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `cblas_zdotc_sub'

The commands I used to compile and link are:

compile:

g++ -I/home/l/intel/mkl/include -w  -c test.cpp -o test.o

link:

g++ -I/home/l/intel/mkl/include -w  -L"/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64" "/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64"/libmkl_intel_lp64.a -Wl,--start-group "/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64"/libmkl_intel_thread.a "/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64"/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -L"/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/../compiler/lib/intel64" -liomp5 -lpthread -lm ./test.o -L/home/l/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -o template

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.3, intel composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> g++ ... "/home/l/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.6.233/mkl/lib/intel64"/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ... -liomp5 -lpthread -lm ./test.o ...

This command line is incorrect. The order of objects and libraries on the link line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html), and you've got it exactly opposite of what it should be. Move `test.o` *before* the libraries, and it will just work (TM).